# How can I 'nohup' a command and log the output of 'time'

Tags: linux, bash

I want to time a long running script, and log the output of the `time` command to a log file, like so:

```
(time php mylongcommand.php) &> dump
```

This works, but what if I want to `nohup` the command so I can check the logs later. The following code does not work:

```
nohup (time php mylongcommand.php) &>dump &
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you putting brackets around the command? That runs it in a sub-shell, which will screw up the nohup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(time php mylongcommand.php) &> dump < /dev/null &
```

Should also do the trick. By redirecting input from `/dev/null` and using `&` to put the process into the background, the same effect is obtained as if you used `nohup`. You should be able to exit your shell session without any stopped jobs error, and the process will continue to run.

Comment: An explanation might help.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work in Zsh (though it does in Bash).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets:

```
nohup time php mylongcommand.php &> dump &
```

Comment: What? The redirection?

Comment: Yes. `&>` means redirect both stdout and stderr, equivalent to `> dump 2>&1`.

Comment: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete says "The latter form is especially uncommon and should never be used", where "latter form" is `>&`